# Add multiple Text Components within an existing View Component - REACT NATIVE

Tags: react-native

My Component is composed something like this. The state contains the article object, details about the article and this object in turn contains the content array, which is where I intend to store the Text nodes.

```
state = {
    article: {
        content: [],
        datePosted: null,
    },
};
```

What I am currently doing is that I am creating an array from the content that I receive. In this manner:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;

    // id is the id of the article in the database
    const id = navigation.getParam("id", "0");


    // getDataFromLocalDb is just a fetch call

    getDataFromLocalDb(`articles/${id}`).then((article) => {
        const content = article.content
            .split("\n\n")
            .map(
                (item, index) => (
                    <Text style={ { marginTop: 5, marginBottom: 5 } } key={ index }>{item}</Text>
                ),
            );

        console.log(content);

        this.setState(prevState => ({
            article: {
                ...prevState.article,
                content,
            },
    }));
});
```

Within the return value of the render method, my code is this:

```
<View
    style={
        {
            marginHorizontal: 20,
            marginTop: 5,
            marginBottom: 5,
        }
    }
>
    { this.state.article.content }
</View>
```

**Desired Output of the above is:**

```
<View
    style={
        {
            marginHorizontal: 20,
            marginTop: 5,
            marginBottom: 5,
        }
    }
>
    <Text style={ { marginTop: 5, marginBottom: 5 } } key={ 1 }>Line of content</Text>
    <Text style={ { marginTop: 5, marginBottom: 5 } } key={ 2 }>Some other line of content</Text>
    .
    .
    .
    .
    <Text style={ { marginTop: 5, marginBottom: 5 } } key={ n }>nth line of content</Text>

</View>
```

**I am unable to figure out the correct and most peformant way of doing this?**

Comment: Do you have any problems with the output? If you do, could you show an example? Your code looks correct to me, don't know if there is some way significantly more performant.

Comment: I could try doing it. Will create a snack on Expo in a few hours.

Comment: Are you sure  this.setState(prevState => ({
            article: {
                ...prevState.article,
                content,
            }, is correct?

Comment: @Chandini do you mean my syntax is correct? :)

Comment: yeah, I was thinking it should be something like  this.setState(prevState => ({ return {article: { ...prevState.article, content,}.}}))

Comment: @Chandini as it turns out, that syntax is 101% correct.. JavaScript becomes less weirder once you start getting used to it. :)

Comment: @Chandini this discussion is going off topic. Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180770/discussion-between-incorelabs-and-chandini).